# Dysfunctional....dplyr functions not running in custom function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

For my research I assemble data sets of various sizes (100 to 50000 lines) and complexities (2 to 6 grouping variables), but often conduct the same set of calculations on all the data sets. I often write R code specific to each data set, but this is becoming time consuming. Now I am attempting to write flexible functions to carry out the calculations. I am comfortable with the package `dplyr`, but am having trouble incorporating `dplyrs` functions into my custom functions. Any general advice is welcome, but below is my current problem.

I am trying to make this example as realistic as possible, so I hope that I this example clearly articulates my current problem. I am trying to feed `DATA` with 4 grouping variables into a function that calculates an average per `TAXA`, `GENUS`, `HABITAT`, and `DATE`. Then I need the function to arrange the `DATES` within each `TAXA` and `GENUS`. My function below is throwing all kinds of errors. I have included the desired `RESULT`. Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

```
DATA
 DATE   HABITAT TAXA    GENUS   1   2
06/30/13    Pool    51  A   10  10
06/30/13    Pool    51  A   4   4
06/30/13    Riff    51  A   1   1
06/30/13    Riff    51  A   3   3
07/27/13    Pool    51  A   10  10
07/27/13    Pool    51  A   4   4
07/27/13    Riff    51  A   1   1
07/27/13    Riff    51  A   3   3
06/30/13    Pool    43  B   10  10
06/30/13    Pool    43  B   4   4
06/30/13    Riff    43  B   1   1
06/30/13    Riff    43  B   3   3
07/27/13    Pool    43  B   10  10
07/27/13    Pool    43  B   4   4
07/27/13    Riff    43  B   1   1
07/27/13    Riff    43  B   3   3
```

Different grouping variables. My idea is to setup these generic grouping vectors at the beginning of the code and then feed them into the functions. The number of variables in these generic grouping variables will change depending the data set being analyzed. For example, TAXA.INFO could include 4 grouping #variables and there could be and additional GROUP.2 and GROUP.3.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate) 

TAXA.INFO = c("TAXA", "GENUS")
GROUP.1 = c("HABITAT")

PROD = c(TAXA.INFO, GROUP.1)
DATE = c("DATE")

AVERAGE.ABUNDANCE = function(x, y, z, a)
  {group_by_(x, y, z) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>%
     ungroup()%>%
     group_by_(a)%>%
     arrange(mdy(z))
  }

XX = AVERAGE.ABUNDANCE(DATA, PROD, DATE, TAXA.INFO)

RESULT
DATE    HABITAT TAXA    GENUS   1   2
06/30/13    Pool    51  A   7   7
06/30/13    Riff    51  A   2   2
07/27/13    Pool    51  A   7   7
07/27/13    Riff    51  A   2   2
06/30/13    Pool    43  B   7   7
06/30/13    Riff    43  B   2   2
07/27/13    Pool    43  B   7   7
07/27/13    Riff    43  B   2   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in the `arrange(mdy(z))` part. You need to be careful to pay attention to which values are character vectors and which are proper symbols that can be evaluated in the context of your data frame. You might consider changing your function to

```
AVERAGE.ABUNDANCE = function(x, y, z, a) {
     group_by_(x, .dots=c(y, z)) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>%
     ungroup()%>%
     group_by_(.dots=a)%>%
     arrange_(.dots=lazyeval::interp(~mdy(x), x=as.name(z)))
  }
```

then this works

```
AVERAGE.ABUNDANCE(DATA, PROD, DATE, TAXA.INFO)
#   TAXA GENUS HABITAT     DATE X1 X2
# 1   43     B    Pool 06/30/13  7  7
# 2   43     B    Riff 06/30/13  2  2
# 3   43     B    Pool 07/27/13  7  7
# 4   43     B    Riff 07/27/13  2  2
# 5   51     A    Pool 06/30/13  7  7
# 6   51     A    Riff 06/30/13  2  2
# 7   51     A    Pool 07/27/13  7  7
# 8   51     A    Riff 07/27/13  2  2
```